How does highly imbalanced test data in certain splits of k-fold time-series cross-validation affect model performance?
I am working on a time-series classification (TSC) problem using k-fold time-series cross-validation (TSCV) to evaluate the performance of my models. My training data for each split is fairly balanced, class distributions ranging from 40% to 60% with a few rare cases of 30/70%. However, I noticed that the test data in some splits is highly imbalanced. For instance, in a 6-fold TSCV setup, splits 2, 5, and 6 have highly imbalanced test sets. I am concerned about how this imbalance might affect my model evaluation.
Here is a brief overview of my setup:
Class Distribution in Training and Testing Data:
Training data: Balanced (40-60% class distribution). Testing data: Highly imbalanced in certain splits (e.g., splits 2, 5, and 6). I'm using standard metrics to evaluate performance; Accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1 Score, AUC-ROC score.
I use the walk-forward time-series cross-validation method to split the data. I used Python with pandas and scikit-learn to analyze the class distribution and model performance across splits. I've used models like LSTM-FCN, InceptionTime, ResNet, TCN, and ROCKET for TSC. In this example, I am working with time series data where each time step represents a data point in a series. The target variable, Fault_Status, indicates whether a fault is present (1) or not (0) at each time step.
Below is a dummy example related to my problem and it is not the actual dataset. It only serves as a means to convey the point.
Specific Questions:

Impact on Experiment:

How might the imbalanced test data in certain splits (e.g., splits 2, 5, and 6) affect the overall evaluation of my TSC models?

Mitigation Strategies:

What strategies can I use to mitigate the negative effects of this imbalance?
Is stratified splitting appropriate for TSC, and how can I implement it?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

def walk_forward_tscv(X, y, n_splits=7):
    tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=n_splits)
    splits = []
    
    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(tscv.split(X)):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        
        unique, counts_train = np.unique(y_train, return_counts=True)
        train_distribution = dict(zip(unique, counts_train))
        
        unique, counts_test = np.unique(y_test, return_counts=True)
        test_distribution = dict(zip(unique, counts_test))
        
        splits.append((train_index, test_index))
        
        print(f"Split {i+1}:")
        print(f"  Training set class distribution: {train_distribution}")
        print(f"  Testing set class distribution: {test_distribution}")
        print("-" * 50)
        
    return splits



Welcome to Cross Validated! It seems like there are periods when the probability is low. If you struggle to predict when that will be, the model performing poorly seems to be telling you that.
